# Joomla's Hathor template pagination not working with custom backend component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Wrote a custom backend component, been working fine.  A subset of users were only allowed access to that so I created a modified template from Hathor to eliminate everything I couldn't using permissions.

Found out that the pagination isn't working for just Hathor.  I tried it with Bluestork and it worked fine.  I also tested article pagination with both Hathor (original and unmodified) and Bluestork and both worked.  Don't see any errors popping up either.

What could be causing the pagination in my component to not work with Hathor?

Here's the code I'm using for pagination:

**Model:**

```
...other query stuff...
//Column ordering
    $orderCol = $this->getState('list.ordering');  //Ordering
    $orderDirn = $this->getState('list.direction'); //Direction

    if ($orderCol != '') {
        $query->order($db->getEscaped($orderCol.' '.$orderDirn));
    } //end column ordering

    return $query;
}
```

**view.html.php**

```
public function display($tpl = null)
{
    $this->items = $this->get('Items');
    $this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination'); //getting this automatically and being assigned to the view
    $this->state = $this->get('State');  //for published state drop down
```

**default.php:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="filter_order" value"<?php echo $listOrder; ?>" /> <!-- for sorting -->
<input type="hidden" name="filter_order_Dir" value"<?php echo $listDirn; ?>" /> <!-- for list direction -->
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what could be going on?

Comment: When you say "the pagination isn't working" what are you actually seeing? (*e.g. all the records/none of them/something else*) Also you're asking about a "pagination" problem but the section of from `default.php` you listed is in respect to filtering...

Comment: Thanks for responding - sorry it took so long to get back.  It just showed a `#` in the URL and went to the top of the page without doing anything.  I wound up including the files for a modal window which fixed it (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up comparing a few of the admin templates output in Chrome and found there was a significant amount of code not being pulled in.  It seemed to be related to a modal window, so I added this under the include head line in my template:

`<?php JHtml::_('behavior.modal'); ?>`

I guess the pagination uses the same js files.  Not sure why it wasn't pulling in, maybe because I restricted access to so much of the backend it didn't think it was used?

At any rate - fixed!

Answer (score 0):

this could happen for a conflict with the form "adminform", either you have two or none and your default Joomla navigation doesn't work (nor do some of the buttons above)